# How to generalize the area of a kite inscribed within a circle

Tags: geometry, circles, area

How exactly would one generalize the area of a kite inscribed within a circle? Through a lot of calculation, which I do think was actually way more complicated then required, using various trigonometric functions, chords, amongst other things, I found that the area in a unit circle would be $\sqrt{3}$. But how exactly would this be generalized?

I am thinking that one would draw a line $r$ to the centre of a circle from the edge, and draw a line across the entire circle. Draw a line starting at the point a of the original line, and go down perpendicular to the central line. Then connect all the points which hit the edges to eachother. Creating a kite.

This should allow one to find an isosceles triangle with the hypotenuses being $r$, with a height of $r$ thus the base can be $r\sqrt{3}$. This should be the side of a larger triangle, which is actually an equilateral, which would have area calculated by $\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}r r(\sqrt{3})^2$, or $\sqrt{3} × 3r^2$.

The second can be found by finding how two other cords, can make up another equilateral, showing that the hypotenuses of the bottom triangles are actually equal to *r*, thus it is an isosceles with the side lengths of $r$ and base of $r 
\sqrt{3}$.

However, we need to find the height with $(\sqrt{3}/2) × (r \sqrt{3})$ or $3r/2$, making the height of the smaller triangle $r/2$, thus the area is $\sqrt{3} r^2$.

Thus the generalized formula should be $r^2\sqrt{3}$

This should be correct, but I am open to people pointing out me messing up or overcomplicating this formula.

[image]

Noticed the small gap, that is not supposed to be there, I just suck at editing images, imagine it touches the central line.

Comment: You need to add a diagram to illustrate your argument. Otherwise it is difficult to follow sufficiently to find your error. There is an error since the area of a kite inscribed in a circle can be anywhere from zero up to the area of a square inscribed in a circle.

Comment: I expected this, exact parametres can be hard to describe. I am gonna add an example

Comment: It appears that you are working with a kite of specific proportions.

Comment: I am, yeah, that is why I attempted to explain the proportions. I just failed. I have added an image.

Comment: You are working specifically with a kite with one edge equal to $r$. In that case, the line drawn to the center will form an equlateral triangle. The height of the equilateral will be $h=(\sqrt{3}/2)r$. But this is also the height of half the kite, which has a base of length $2r$. So the area of half the kite will be $bh/2$ or $\sqrt{3}r^2/2$. But that is just the area of half the kite, which will be $\sqrt{3}r^2$. In general, however, a kite does not have to have one side of length $r$.

Comment: So my math was right, albeit I went through far more than I had to?

Comment: Yes, it appears to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $ABCD$ be the cyclic kite in question, with diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ and $X$ their intersection. Let $O$ be the centre of the circle and $r$ its radius.

[image: A kite inscribed in a circle]

**Lemma 1:** One diagonal of a kite is the perpendicular bisector of the other diagonal. Without loss of generality, assume $AC$ bisects $BD$.

**Lemma 2:** The perpendicular bisector of a chord of a circle is a diameter of the circle.

Hence $AC$ is a diameter of the circle and $|AC|=2r$.

**Lemma 3 (Thales’ theorem):** A triangle constructed on a diameter of its circumcircle is a right triangle, with the right angle at the vertex not on the diameter.

Hence $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle ADC$ are right triangles with $AC$ the hypotenuse of each. They are congruent by SSS ($|AB|=|AD|$ and $|BC|=|DC|$ by definition of a kite; $AC$ common), each having half the kite’s area.

---

Consider $\triangle ABC$. The altitude $BX$ is constrained such that $0<|BX|\le r$ (length $0$ is the degenerate case where $A$ and $B$ coincide, and length $r$ is the case where $|AC|=|BD|$ and $ABCD$ is a square).

Hence the area $\mathrm{A}_{ABC}$ is constrained to $0<\mathrm{A}_{ABC}\le r^2$, and since it’s half of $ABCD$, we have bounds on the area $\mathrm{A}_{ABCD}$:

$$0<\mathrm{A}_{ABCD}\le 2r^2$$

---

For the special case in the question, where $|AB|=r$, $\triangle ABO$ is equilateral (since $AO$ and $BO$ are also radii) and its altitude is $|BX|=\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}r$. Hence $\mathrm{A}_{ABC}=\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}r^2$ and:

$$\mathrm{A}_{ABCD}=\sqrt 3 r^2$$

Comment: Thanks again for showing me I did it right. And yeah, I knew about the 2r<sup>2</sup> situation, which is a square..

Answer (score 1):

If the height of the smaller part
is $h$,
where $h \le r$,
the height of the upper part
is $2r-h$.

The distance $d$
from the center
to the crossbar
is $r-h$,
so,
if $c$ is half the length
of the crossbar,
$r^2
=c^2+(r-h)^2
=c^2+r^2-2rh+h^2
$
so
$c^2=2rh-h^2
$.

The area of the lower half is
$2(ch/2)
=ch
$
and the area of the upper half is
$2(c(2r-h))/2
=c(2r-h)
$
so the combined area is
$ch+c(2r-h)
=2rc
=2r\sqrt{2rh-h^2}
$.

Checks.

If the crossbar
is in the middle,
$c=h=r$
so the area is
$2r^2$
which is correct
since each triangle
has base $2r$
and altitude $r$.

If the crossbar is at the bottom,
$h=0$
so the area is also $0$
which is correct
since the kite
is a stick.

Note that

$\begin{array}\\
2r(2r-h)-(2r-h)^2
&=4r^2-2rh-(4r^2-4rh+h^2)\\
&=2rh-h^2\\
\end{array}
$

so the expression for the area
is the same when
$h$
(the lower height)
is replaced by
$2r-h$
(the upper height).

Comment: Another confirmation that my math was right, yes. Also another example of a far easier way I could do it. Lol.